# PHP Mysqli not closing TCP connections

Tags: php, tcp, mysqli, connection

I'm updating my scripts to move from ext/mysql to ext/mysqli. It's introduced some problems.

Under ext/mysqli, connections are not released when a script terminates.

The scripts are all run from the command line. There is no Apache or other HTTP involvement.

For business reasons, I sometimes need to have a large number of single DB interactions. They aren't concurrently active, each action (INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT, DELETE) is completed before the next is commenced.
In come cases, I am able to build large single queries (eg UPDATE...SET...CASE...WHEN etc) and these aren't a problem as they use fewer connections, of course, but there are occasions where I cannot use this option.

I have a `$mysqli->close()` after each DB operation, but the (TCP) connections do not close. After the script has terminated, the connections remain open until they time out (as shown by “netstat -an”).

The practical implication for me is that I am running out of TCP connections.

These scripts perform perfectly with ext/mysql.

This has been previously reported as a bug (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38107) but the solution was to upgrade to PHP 5.3. I'm using 5.3.8.

Example:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME,DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE)         or die ("Unable to connect: " . $mysqli->error());
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die ("Query failed: " . $mysqli->error . " Actual query: " . $query);
// Do domething interesting with $result
$mysqli->close();
/** TCP connection remains open until it times out at an OS level /**
```

Has anyone experienced this problem and found a solution? Thanks.

NB: There are other questions on Stackoverflow which are similar, but not the same. Please don't close this as a duplicate.

UPDATE: I may be barking up the wrong tree. The reason I believe it is a connection issue is because I am getting this error:
`mysqli::mysqli(): [2002] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.`
The explanation I found here (http://www.online-it-support.co.uk/?p=652) suggests TCP port exhaustion is the cause.
I can make changes to my development environment as it's within my control. The production environment isn't.
I assumed - perhaps unwisely - that this was incorrect behavior. this was based on the fact that the problem does not occur with ext/mysql.
Perhaps my question ought to be "how to I make ext/mysqli behave like ext/mysql?".

Comment: Sorry, tried to format Example as code but I failed.

Comment: Technically, you shouldn't close the connection after each operation. Unless you have multiple connections with different credentials to different dbs/servers, a DB connection CAN and SHOULD be re-used. ->close() should only be called when you KNOW you're finished with db operations.

Comment: Wouldn't that make things worse? Or at least no better.

Comment: What state are the connections in as reported by netstat? What do you mean by "running out of TCP connections"? Are you running out of local ports? Or a connection limit on your database software? Or what?

Comment: I'm not saying you should never close, I'm just saying that repeated open/do something/close/open/do something/close is usually pointless and wasteful. open/do stuff/do stuff/do stuff/close is a more typical pattern

Comment: Netstat shows the status of the connections as TIME_WAIT

Comment: @SimonRoberts: Then they're already closed. The [TIME_WAIT](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.7.shtml) state means the connection is closed.

Comment: I haven't investigated whether it is the OS or Mysql that is running out of ports. It seemed to me that the issue is to reduce the number of open ports, not make config changes to allow for them.

Comment: @SimonRoberts: The behavior you are seeing is normal and not a bug or issue. The connections are closed. What connection rate are you trying to make work? About how many connections per second? (Most likely, you need to change your design to reuse your connections rather than trying to keep tearing them down and building them back up.)

Comment: @SimonRoberts To see if a connection is open to MySQL, you should be using `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` from the `mysql` client, not just looking at sockets.

Comment: Pls see UPDATE section on question. Thanks.

Comment: @SimonRoberts: See the last paragraph of my answer. Before you were reusing TCP connections, now you're not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connections in `TIME_WAIT` state *are* closed. There's no bug or issue. If you create and close large numbers of TCP connections in a small amount of time, you'll wind up with lots of TCP connections in `TIME_WAIT` state.

You either need to re-use your connections rather than closing them or figure out why this is causing you a problem and fix it. For example, increasing the range of local ports may help.

Building up and tearing down a TCP connection is expensive. If you're trying to do that dozens of times a second, you're doing something very wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on "re-use your connections" please?

Comment: @SimonRoberts: Don't close the connection because that forces you to open a new one. Instead, leave the connection open until the script is done, that way it can be reused. Building up and tearing down a TCP connection for each request is not sensible. *You* put a close after each operation. You said so in the question. That's why you have so many closed connections.

Comment: Thank you. I've done a re-write as per your suggestion and the problem has ceased. So it was bad scripting on my part that was causing the problem. I guess that ext/mysql must have been more dummy-tolerant. I can see why my logic took me where it did, but you were spot on with your diagnosis and solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the persistent connections in [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

> Prepending host by p: opens a persistent connection.
>   mysqli_change_user() is automatically called on connections opened
>   from the connection pool.

That should leave the connections open, in a usable state.